# C++ cast std::vector<char*> to char**

Tags: c++, casting, stdvector

How can I cast *or convert* a std::vector to char** in C++?

I'm using std::vector because I need to push_back some strings inside a loop, but then I have to call a C function that requires a char**.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) will produce `char**` , although this pointer can get invalidated if reallocation happens on the vector.

Also, `&vec[0]` is another technique for producing a mutable pointer, but you need to be careful with this approach.

Comment: "but you need to be carefull with this approach." -- why?

Comment: because C has no idea of objects , constructors or destructors. so because the expression &vec[x] is mutable, extra care should be taken when dealing with C API's - the library might even try to `realloc` the whole data structure!

Comment: @TheOperator: For the same reasons as `data` (reallocation on the vector can invalidate it), and because unlike `data`, `&vec[0]` is often legitimate code for non-`vector` types with non-contiguous storage, but if you tried to use it like a pointer to array (legal with `vector`) and accessed neighboring memory, it would be undefined behavior. Also, not sure on this, but I suspect a `vector` of references might behave "interestingly" (getting the address of the element referenced, not the reference itself; am I right on that?)

Comment: The answer sounds as if `&vec[0]` were more dangerous than `data()`, but there's no reason given ("you need to be careful" is not too helpful). @ShadowRanger STL containers cannot hold references.

Comment: @TheOperator: Thanks, wasn't sure. Never felt the need to try (I'd consider an attempt to do it to be code smell by people who don't understand automatic/stack variables). But yeah, I suspect the main reason to prefer `data` is that stuff like `std::deque` would allow you to take `&seq[0]` and use it as a `char**`, but using it as a C-style array would be undefined behavior. Using `data` lets the compiler verify easily that you're using a `vector` (or something else with `data`), not just a sequence that offers `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the data method for this : 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data
which will return a pointer to the vectors data